# Displaying a frame every Xth of a second in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

i'm currently in the process of making a game for a **real-time system** school project.

I need to be able to **display a frame every 1/60th of a second** (or explain why I can't do such a thing, if it's not possible).

Using AndEngine GLES2.
I tried looking in the AndEngine library, but i'm fairly new to Android development (as well as using AndEngine), so I couldn't find anything that would guide me in the right direction.

Thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: Hoping my post may help you.Have a look at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display frames :

```
final FPSCounter fpsCounter = new FPSCounter();
this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(fpsCounter);

final Text fpsText = new Text(250, 240, this.mFont, "FPS:", "FPS: XXXXX".length(),vbo);

scene.attachChild(fpsText);

scene.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(1 / 20.0f, true, new ITimerCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler)
    {
        fpsText.setText("FPS: " + fpsCounter.getFPS());
    }
}));
```

If you want to set FrameRate:

```
Instead of new Engine(...), use new LimitedFPSEngine(EngineOptions pEngineOptions, int pFramesPerSecond);.
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly display a frame every Xth of a second, for example if I choose 60 FPS I see the FPSCounter going up extremely fast at first but never really reaching 60.0 fps. However, the engine does its best to respect the preferred fps and i don't think there's any better way of doing this. Thanks for your quick answer.